Broken Process Pool: Processpool executor inside django app hosted on apache
I have a django application that I would like to host on my apache server. Use case of the application is to receive requests and performs compute intensive operations over a set of given inputs. To parallelise my computations I used future.ProcessPool executor in the core of the django app. Parallelisation in indispensable for my application.
While the above setup works locally, I face BrokenProcessPool error especially when the app is hosted on the apache server. Tried few tricks in some related questions (here) but I have no clear idea what is happening or how to resolve it. Could someone please help me understand:

Technically, what is the underlying issue in my setup?
How do I resolve it without massively changing my existing framework(Django, Apache)?
Can you provide me references for an ideal workflow used in some well known data-science or graphics web applications using Django and parallel computations. This could help me revise my current framework.

Below is some relevant information

views.py looks like
 import core.ray_trace

  def get_heatmap(request):
     list_of_inputs = request.POST.get('inputs')
      # parallel computation of list happens inside raytrace
      response_data = ray_trace(list_of_inputs)
      return JsonResponse(response_data, status=200)


Apache config for my project
   WSGIDaemonProcess sp python-path=/home/ubuntu/_/spaceplanning python-home=/home/ubuntu/_/venv processes=3 threads=10 request-timeout=600
   WSGIProcessGroup sp
   WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/_/sp/spAPI/wsgi.py


ps aux | grep apache


Error message and Traceback: concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.



I read switching my frame work to Celery or gunicorn server could help but honestly I could not catch on the intricates of the details provided.
Finally, are there any good web hosting services catering for data science and graphics applications that I could just use to unburden myself from hosting?
